# Flutter Exception "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'" when fetching filtered api data

Tags: android, django, flutter, api, django-rest-framework

I'm making an Android app with local Django Restful Api. I have 2 models in database, that are nested together, ShowsModel and DirectorModel. This is basically how my JSON looks like with GET function.

```
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shows name",
        "annotation": "Some long text",
        "image": "/media/images/poster.jpg"
        "director": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "First name",
            "surname": "Last name",
            "image": "/media/images/portrait.jpg"
        },
    },
]
```

I need to filter shows by director id and display them. I changed up views.py in my Django, and added some functions, like

```
        check_director = self.request.query_params.get('check_director', None)
        if check_director:
            queryset = queryset.filter(director=check_director)

        serializer = ShowsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It works, now I have this key parameter check_director, and when I add value 1, it shows only that data, which contains director with id 1.

Now, the problem is in Flutter.

I have director detail page, that requires id, which it gets from another screen. I use this function to get data from DirectorsModel in Django Api.

```
Future<void> getDirectorInfo() async {
  directorModel = await APIHandler.getDirectorsById(id: widget.id);
  setState(() {});
}
```

It works, no problem. But how do I fetch data from ShowsModel?
I'm trying this function for api:

```
 static Future<ShowsModel> getShowsByDirector({required String director}) async {
  try {
      var uri = Uri.parse(
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000/showapi?check_director=1", //instead =1 it should be =$id
      );
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      print("response ${jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))}");
      var data = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)));
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw data["message"];
      }
      return ShowsModel.fromJson(data);
    } catch (error) {
      log("an error occured while getting show info $error");
      throw error.toString();
    }
  }
```

But unfortunately I'm getting this error `Exception has occurred. "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'"`

It prints correct results, when I use Future builder:

```
FutureBuilder<ShowsModel>(
    future: APIHandler.getShowsByDirector(),
    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
            ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "An error occured ${snapshot.error}"),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
          const Center(
            child: Text("No shows has been added yet"),
          );
        }
        return const Text('we good');
    })),
```

But I still get the same error.
Right now I'm just checking connection and results, as I said in the comment, this function will have to require id...

In the director detail page, I have this code, but I believe it's not correct at all.

```
class DirectorDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DirectorDetailPage({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);
  final String id;
  @override
  State<DirectorDetailPage> createState() => _DirectorDetailPageState();
}

class _DirectorDetailPageState extends State<DirectorDetailPage> {
  DirectorModel? directorModel;
  ShowsModel? showsModel;
  Future<void> getDirectorInfo() async {
    directorModel = await APIHandler.getDirectorsById(id: widget.id);
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> getDirectorShows() async {
    showsModel = await APIHandler.getShowsByDirector();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    getDirectorInfo();
    getDirectorShows();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

// Widget build code which displays director information

// This container should show me one name from the database
 Container(
           margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
           child: showsModel == null
            ? const Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
           : Text(showsModel!.name),
          ),
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are a few issues with your code that might be causing the problems you're facing. Let's go over them:

1. **String instead of integer:**

   In your error message `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`, it seems that you are trying to use a String where an int is expected. Without more details on where this error comes from, it's hard to provide a concrete solution. However, I suspect it's because the `getShowsByDirector` function expects a string argument called `director` which you are not providing when calling the function.
2. **Passing director id to `getShowsByDirector` function:**

   You need to pass the director's id when calling the `getShowsByDirector` function. Your `getShowsByDirector` function expects a `director` parameter but you're not providing it when you're calling it in `getDirectorShows` method. This id will then be used in the API URL to fetch the shows related to this director.

Change your `getDirectorShows` to:

```dart
Future<void> getDirectorShows() async {
  showsModel = await APIHandler.getShowsByDirector(director: widget.id);
  setState(() {});
}
```

And then your `getShowsByDirector` function to:

```dart
static Future<ShowsModel> getShowsByDirector({required String director}) async {
  try {
      var uri = Uri.parse(
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000/showapi?check_director=${director}",
      );
      // rest of the code
  }
}
```

3. **Parsing the response data:**

   The response from your API is a list of show objects. However, you're trying to parse it as a single `ShowsModel` object. This is probably where the `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'` error is coming from. You should parse it as a list of `ShowsModel` objects instead.

   Your `getShowsByDirector` function should look something like this:

```dart
static Future<List<ShowsModel>> getShowsByDirector({required String director}) async {
  try {
      var uri = Uri.parse(
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000/showapi?check_director=${director}",
      );
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      print("response ${jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))}");
      var data = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)));
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw data["message"];
      }
      return (data as List).map((show) => ShowsModel.fromJson(show)).toList();
    } catch (error) {
      log("an error occured while getting show info $error");
      throw error.toString();
    }
  }
```

And change `getDirectorShows` method to:

```dart
Future<void> getDirectorShows() async {
  showsModelList = await APIHandler.getShowsByDirector(director: widget.id);
  setState(() {});
}
```

And declare `showsModelList` at the top of your `_DirectorDetailPageState` class:

```dart
List<ShowsModel>? showsModelList;
```

This should parse your API response correctly and give you a list of shows for the director. You'll also need to update your UI to handle a list of shows instead of a single show.

Comment: Thank you, it's working correctly now!!! If it's not too much trouble, can you also help me with UI? Is there a way to convert this list to string? For example, I need to display a name from every show under this list in ListBuilder, how do I do it?

Comment: Since you're retrieving a list of shows (`List<ShowsModel>`), you can use the `ListView.builder` widget to display the name from every show in this list like this:

'''
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: showsModelList?.length ?? 0,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Text(showsModelList![index].name);
  },
)
'''

The `itemCount` is set to the length of your `showsModelList`, and if this list is null, it defaults to 0. The `itemBuilder` function is called for each item in the list. It returns a `Text` widget with the show's name.